# How to center text in MS Word with Python win32com

Tags: python, ms-word, format, win32com

I'm automating the creation of an MS Word document and part of the code utilizes win32com to update the table of contents and the header.  The function that does this looks like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32

def updateHeaderAndTOC(docx_file, headerText):
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
    doc = word.Documents.Open(docx_file)
    word.ActiveDocument.Sections(1)\
        .Headers(win32.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary)\
        .Range.Text=headerText
    doc.TablesOfContents(1).Update()
    doc.Close(SaveChanges=True)
```

This seems to work fine.  The problem is that when the header text gets replaced, for some reason, the header gets left justified, instead of being centered the way it was before I changed the header text.

Does somebody know how to

1. Prevent this left justification from happening and/or
2. Center the text again after the text has changed?

Comment: I made a test file with a center-justified, single-paragraph header. Your code did not cause my header to left-justify. In your target word file, maybe centering was achieved with a center-tab? If that's the case you could append a `\t` to the start of header text.

Comment: The header I'm replacing has 2 lines (2 paragraphs), and the one it is being replaced with also has 2 lines/paragraphs.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem replacing a 2-para header with something like `headerText='foo\rbar\r'. I could reproduce the problem if after the 2 centered header paragraphs there was a 3rd empty left-justified paragraph.

Comment: As it turns out, in the original document I had the first line of the header centered, but the 2nd line was not centered.  When I replaced the text, the replaced header defaulted to the formatting of the 2nd line instead of the first line.  This behavior is a bit quirky, but at least I understand what was happening now.  Thanks for your help @xidgel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the results of the comments section, there is no way for win32com to center text in a header.  The solution, at least in this case, was to make sure that the formatting in the document was correct on **ALL** modified lines before trying to modify the text.  If your application requires you to modify text, then change the formatting (center, left-justified, etc.) after that header text is changed, win32com can't help...at least today.

Answer (score -1):

Using the the .Paragraphs.Alignment property of the header object as defined below can indeed align the header.

```
import win32com.client

wrdApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fullFilePathAndName, False)
header = doc.Sections(1).Headers(win32com.client.constants.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
header.Text = "some new header goes here"

#this will align the header content
header.Paragraphs.Alignment = win32com.client.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
```